# How to explain in layman's terms for this function (function, list, in and isinstance)?

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, isinstance

I came across this function:

```
 def count_list(l):          
      count = 0          
      for e in l:               
           if isinstance(e, list):                    
                count = count + 1 + count_list(e)                    
      return count
```

I couldn't understand it especially the `for e in 1` and `isinstance(e, list)`, wonder if any pro can explain? Just started learning function, `list`, `in` and `isinstance`

Comment: I'm no pro, but that's definitely a lower `L` not a 1.

Comment: yeah you are right. And i only know this function suppose to count a nested list and tell how many nested list inside a list. But i can't understand what does this code means in logical manner.

Comment: It's a good learning moment. I suggest you run it on a few examples, and add some `print`s in important parts of the function to check out what is going on.

That said - this function is recursive, which maybe is a tiny bit advanced topic until you grasp the rest of the basic stuff (but as long as you know understand functions, you can understand recursion)

Comment: Read up on this in [the official Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) and run the examples in there for yourself.

Comment: Hey thanks @Adam.Er8 and @ usr2564301 for the advice. I did some print and quickly read and can guess that the function means.... for every element (e) in the list (l), if the (e) match/ found in the list (l), + 1 to count until nothing can be found, then exit the function. I have a question, so i can indicate "l" or "L" as a short form for List ? As for (e), it seemed i can name it anyway i want and still goes fine. But for (l), I can't change to any alphabet or a error will show.

Comment: @Newbiecoder you have other issues, `list` instead of `l` is forbidden, but here is an exemple where `arg` is used instead of `l`. https://repl.it/repls/OpulentDarkorangeRegister

Comment: @Orace Thanks. I think i know where you are coming from. For multiple nested list mixed with keys, my code may have problems. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's read it:

```
# define the method count_list that take one argument l (lower L)
def count_list(l):
    # define count to be a int with value 0
    count = 0
    # for each item e in l (we supose that l can be itered)
    for e in l:
        # if e is a list
        if isinstance(e, list):
            # add one to count and the result of count_list called on e (recursive call)
            count = count + 1 + count_list(e)                    
    return count
```

**Remarks:**

- If `e` is not a list `count` doesn't change. This method increment `count` by one only when a list is found inside `l`.
- It also increment by the number of list in that list in a list.
- Finally it returns the number of nested list in `l`. For each list it meet, it add `1+number of list in that list` using recursive calls.

**Example:**

Here a representation of the content of `l`:

- Element
- ListA

  - Element
  - Element
  - ListB

    - Element
    - Element
  - ListC

    - Element
- Element

What happen when we call `count_list(l)`:

- `count_list` is called with the parameter `l` (call 1).
- The element of `l` are iterated.
- The element `ListA` is a list. `count` (in call 1) is incremented by 1 and the result of the call to `count_list` with the parameter `ListA`.
- `count_list` is called with the parameter `ListA` (call 2).

  - The element of `ListA` are iterated.
  - The element `ListB` is a list. `count` (in call 2) is incremented by 1 and the result of the call to `count_list` with the parameter `ListB`.

    - `count_list` is called with the parameter `ListB` (call 3).
    - The element of `ListB` are iterated.
    - No list are found `0` is returned (call 3)
  - `count` (in call 2) value is the result of `0+1+0`. It's `1`.
  - The element `ListC` is a list. `count` (in call 2) is incremented by 1 and the result of the call to `count_list` with the parameter `ListC`.

    - `count_list` is called with the parameter `ListC` (call 4).
    - The element of `ListC` are iterated.
    - No list are found `0` is returned (call 4)
  - `count` (in call 2) value is the result of `1+1+0`. It's `2`.
  - There is no list left in `ListA`.
  - `2` is returned (call 2)
- `count` (in call 1) value is the result of `0+1+2`. It's `3`.
- There is no list left in `l`.
- `3` is returned (call 1)

Answer (score 2):

Python variables are "dynamic", meaning that the incoming argument `l` (that's a lower case L) does not necessarily have a specific type. It could be an int, or a string, or a list etc.

In this case, if it happens to be a list, the for loop will iterate over each element of that list. The loop checks to see if each of the elements of the list, loaded to variable `e`, is an instance of a list as well. If true, it'll increment the variable `count` by `1` and call back into function `count_list` to calculate the size of that list and add to `count` as well.

Calling into the function you are inside of is what is called a recursive function, so that's what you have here.

The general idea seems to be that this function is trying to calculate the total number of elements in nested lists.

You can try it out in a debugger (PyCharm is a great IDE) to see how exactly it works. Try calling your function like this:

```
count_list([1,2,3,[1,2,3,[1,2],4],4,5,6])
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the help. i also tried to play with the variables to make a guess how it will affect the change of the result. I have a question, so i can indicate "l" or "L" as a short form for List ? As for (e), it seemed i can name it anyway i want and still goes fine. But for (l), I can't change to any alphabet or a error will show but a capital L is fine. So List can be represented by L or l in python huh?

Comment: No there are no restrictions as to what you can name your variables. The type of the variable has no bearing on the naming of the variable either. The only thing in this case is, if you rename `l` to be something else, then you have to rename the incoming variable `l` as well to that same new name. That goes for all the other variables too. You can rename `e` but you have to rename it everywhere it's used otherwise it will either give you an error or your method won't work the same

Comment: Oh. I think i got it... yes...i forgot to notice there is a "l" in count_list(l), hence when i only change the "l" at the bottom, an error show. ok i understand now, the "i" and "e" are just variables inside the function for checking and counting. Thanks alot.